# PHP MySQL library version differs from your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, database, centos

I've just tried updating my mysql version to 5.5 by using the commands below:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
yum --enablerepo=remi update mysql-server
```

It all went well and it says successful. However, when I login to phpmyadmin I get this error message like below:

```
"Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.45 differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.73"
```

I wonder why is my mysql version still 5.1 since I already update it. The weird thing is that I did not even update my php version. It actually updates my php too after running the command above.

Below is the list of php and mysql version that I've installed on my centos server after running the update command above.

```
[root ~]# yum list installed | grep -i mysql
compat-mysql51.x86_64              5.1.54-1.el6.remi                 @remi
mysql.x86_64                       5.5.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
mysql-libs.x86_64                  5.5.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
mysql-server.x86_64                5.5.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64              4.013-3.el6                       @base
php-mysql.x86_64                   5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi

[root ~]# yum list installed | grep -i php
php.x86_64                         5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-bcmath.x86_64                  5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-cli.x86_64                     5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-common.x86_64                  5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-gd.x86_64                      5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-mbstring.x86_64                5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-mcrypt.x86_64                  5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-mysql.x86_64                   5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-pdo.x86_64                     5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-pear.noarch                    1:1.9.4-4.el6                     @base
php-pecl-apc.x86_64                3.1.15-0.4.20130912.el6.remi.5.4  @remi
php-php-gettext.noarch             1.0.11-3.el6                      @epel
php-snmp.x86_64                    5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-tcpdf.noarch                   6.0.091-1.el6                     @epel
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 6.0.091-1.el6                     @epel
php-tidy.x86_64                    5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
php-xml.x86_64                     5.4.45-1.el6.remi                 @remi
phpMyAdmin.noarch                  4.0.10.4-1.el6                    @epel
```

I used to have php version 5.3. But after trying to update mysql, it updates my php to 5.4 somehow. I wonder if I did it wrong. Thanks!

I tried searching for solution on google, but mostly, people have their mysql sever version 'higher' than their php mysql library version. And most people would ask them to update their PHP. But not in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is only a sanity check. Nothing serious, you can ignore it.

But as all seems in sync, it should not appear if you correctly restart mysql and the web server and run mysql_upgrade.

Notice: I also recommend to use **php-mysqlnd** instead of **php-mysql** (same set of extensions, with the PHP native driver). This will also clear this warning.

Comment: may I know how do I switch to use php-mysqlnd?

Comment: yum remove php-mysql; yum install php-mysqlnd  (or use "yum shell" if you don't want to remove other packages which depend on it)